# Django: Make HTML page from SQL query

Tags: python, sql, django

This works but..

`views.py`

```py
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.db import connection

def query():
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute('SELECT some, stuff FROM here;')
        row = cursor.fetchall()

    return row


def index(request):
    return HttpResponse(query())
```

What if I want to get a filtered response that is restricted to a user or group from the admin?

For example, if the user is in the BAIT group they could filter results WHERE email LIKE 'bob@bait.com';

Comment: How does it not work? Do you get any error? Please, check [ask]. Post [mre], incl. full traceback you get.

Comment: If you want to use the admin, try out the tutorial.  Once you understand that, you may be able to find answers to how to restrict displayed results based on the logged in user. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/tutorial07/

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this...

`/opt/my_project/my_app/templates/my_app/generate_html.html`

```html
<html>
<h1>Generate HTML</h1>

<form method="POST" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <button type="submit">Submit Query</button>
</form>

</html>
```

`/opt/my_project/my_project/settings.py`

```py
'DIRS': ['/opt/my_project/my_app/templates/my_app'],
```

`/opt/my_project/my_app/urls.py`

```py
path('generate_html/', generate_html, name = "generate_html"),
```

`/opt/my_project/my_app/forms.py`

```py
from django import forms

class InputForm(forms.Form):
   email = forms.EmailField(max_length = 100)
```

`/opt/my_project/my_app/views.py`

```py
def query(email):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        query = '''SELECT some, stuff
                FROM here
                WHERE email = %s
                ORDER BY stuff;
                '''
        values = (email,)
        cursor.execute(query, values)
        select = cursor.fetchall()

    return select


def generate_html(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST.get('email', None)
        try:
            html = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>' 

            for row in query(email):
                some, stuff = row
                html += 'Row: ' + some + ' ' + stuff + '<br>' 

            html += '<br><br>' + '<a href = "/my_app/generate_html/">Search Again!</a>' + '</body></html>'
            return HttpResponse(html)
        except Exception as e:
            return HttpResponse(str(e))
    else:
        context ={}
        context['form']= InputForm()
        return render(request, "generate_html.html", context)
```